# Automatically trigger PrePros when partial file is saved

Tags: sass, prepros

I have PrePros running.

When I save a partial (ie _partial.scss) I would like to have the main
SCSS file (that imports "_partial.scss) processed

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your partials are properly imported in your main Sass file. Prepros 5 and  6 both have always automatically done this for me using the default settings.